# Plus sign gets replaced by space when posting from wkhtmltopdf to expressjs

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, express, post, wkhtmltopdf

I'm executing a `wkhtmltopdf` command, in full:

```py
email = "myuser+type@sky.net"
password = "123"
base_url = "http://sky.net"
cookie_path = "./cookie.jar"
report_path = "./report.pdf"
token = "abc123"

login_query = \
    ("/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --cookie-jar {cookie_path} "
      "--custom-header content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded "
      "--post email {email} "
      "--post password {password} "
      "--post _csrf {token} "
      "--disable-javascript "
      "{base_url}/login "
      "{report_path}").format(
        cookie_path=cookie_path,
        email=email, password=password,
        base_url=base_url,
        report_path=report_path,
        token=token
    )

subprocess.check_call(login_query, shell=True)
```

And in the ExpressJS server I get it as `myuser type@sky.net`.

I have an `app.use(urlencoded())` middleware set.

When I execute `subprocess.check_call` with a list of strings and without `shell=True` also doesn't help.

I've tried posting a url encoded value `myuser%2Btype@sky.net` and I receive it as is (with `%2B`, not turned to plus sign).

Notable that without the custom header I get this error: `content-type missing in HTTP POST, defaulting to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Use QNetworkRequest::setHeader() to fix this problem.`

Any ideas?

Comment: Is that the full command you are passing to `wkhtmltopdf`?

Comment: @DanielSchroederDev thanks, I've added the full command

Comment: See if you can use that middleware I posted, if not, maybe I can dig a little deeper.

Answer (score 1):

I dug through this a little, and found it has something to do with how the underlying NodeJS `querystring` module is handling the parsing of the incoming query string when `bodyParser.urlencoded` is running. I broke down what `bodyParser` does, and the point at which your `myuser+type` becomes `myuser type` is when `querystring.parse()` converts the query string into individual tokens. As `querystring` relies on the built-in `decodeURIComponent`, or a method similar of it's own, which for some reason seems to be implemented to replace the '+' with a ' ' like [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent#Decoding_query_parameters_from_a_URL), I decided to re-implement this from scratch to fit your use case.

I wrote you a piece of middleware that you can drop in to replace `bodyParser.urlencoded()` for this use-case, which I ran on my machine against your inputs and seemed to fix the issue by avoiding calling `decodeURIComponent()` on the query string, and instead manually parsing. This is by no means robust, but maybe you can amend to your needs as they arise, and add it somewhere in your middleware stack:

```
const parsePayload = (req, res, next) => {

  let body = [];

  req.on('data', chunk => {
    body.push(chunk);
  });

  req.on('end', () => {

    const qs = body.join('');

    req.body = qs.split('&').reduce((acc, cur) => {
      const tokens = cur.split('=');
      acc[tokens[0]] = tokens[1];
      return acc;
    }, {})

    next();

  });

};

app.use(parsePayload);
```

It parses the incoming request Buffer into an array of `Buffers`:

```
let body = [];

req.on('data', chunk => {
  body.push(chunk);
});

// body will look like:
/*
[
  <Buffer 65 6d 61 69 6c 3d 6d 79 75 73 65 72 2b 74 79 70 65 40 73 6b 79 2e 6e 65 74 26 70 61 73 73 77 6f 72 64 3d 31 32 33 26 5f 63 73 72 66 3d 61 62 63 31 32 ... 1 more byte>
]
*/
```

Then converts them into the querystring by calling `join('') on the array:

```
const qs = body.join('');

// qs will look like this now
email=myuser+type@sky.net&password=123&_csrf=abc123
```

Then, we use `split()` to first break the query string (qs) into an array of pairs like:

```
[['email=myuser+type@sky.net'], ['password=123'], etc...]
```

And immediately call `reduce()` to mutate this array into an object, first by splitting each sub-array into it's component parts with `split()`:

```
// cur is the current sub-array inside reduce()
const tokens = cur.split('=');

// tokens will be an array like ['email', 'myuser+type@sky.net']
```

Then we can use these parts as the key/value pair of the `acc`, which will be the returned object from `reduce()` and the value of `req.body`:

```
acc[tokens[0]] = tokens[1];
```

So the data on req.body will be an object in the form of:

```
{ email: 'myuser+type@sky.net', password: '123', _csrf: 'abc123' }
```

Here's a gif of it running against a local instance of Express:

[image: parse]

Comment: Thanks @Daniel! Really appreciate the effort to help and writing this answer! 
My main concern with a custom middleware is that its a low-level layer that has a (pretty) standard lib which was battle tested by millions of users. Also by not calling `decodeURIComponent` how will it handle other values which are URI encoded?

Comment: I was more in the impression that my Python sucks (I'm a JS man) and I'm missing something obvious, although all the obvious solutions I've found didn't help me.

Comment: Hang on, did you need to handle URI encoded stuff? Cause I can add that easily. In fact, it isn't the issue, it think bodyParser does something like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent#Decoding_query_parameters_from_a_URL) which modifies `decodeURIComponent` to add a space for the '+' character.

Comment: I mean that I need a robust middleware for all kinds of requests, some should be properly url decoded. It's possible to write something custom like you did, but it doesn't make sense for my case. Express's urlencoded is pretty much standard, so this is not a part in the chain that I'm willing to replace. For now I've used a workaround with a different user name, without pluses :facepalm: